# binding to html style with a css variable. example [style.background]="'var(--accent-1)'"

Tags: angular, css-variables

My CMS allows hex values to dynamically style html elements. for example if the value of `bgColor` is `#fff` then i can use the following html to set it correctly

```
[style.background]="cms?.bgColor"
```

Now what if the cms value is a preset css variable like `var(--accent-1)` now the same html wont work even though if i use straight css (`background: var(--accent-1)`); it works.

I confirmed this wont work by removing dynamic logic `[style.background]="'var(--accent-1)'"`

#### `[style.background]="'var(--accent-1)'"`

is there some version of this that will work?

Answer (score 0):

try ngStyle directive. its logic just applies style without trying to parse the value

```
[ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: 'var(--accent-1)'}"
```